# Phalcon PHP - attach event manager to router in non-micro app without rolling my own EventsManager

Tags: php, router, phalcon

I'm trying to add something like this into a non-micro app, but I'm unsure of how to go about doing that without rolling my own EventsManager.  Is there a way to get a reference to Phalcon's default EventsManager?

```
$eventsManager->attach("dispatch", function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {

    if ($event->getType() == 'beforeException') {
        switch ($exception->getCode()) {
            case Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
            case Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
                $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'controller' => 'errors',
                    'action' => 'show404'
                ));
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is. Your dispatcher must be injected into your DI as a service with the same name. If your `$eventsManager` is an instance of `Phalcon\DI\Injectable`:

```
$this->dispatcher->forward(…); 
$this->di->get('dispatcher')->forward(…);
```

If not:

```
DI::getDefault()->get('dispatcher')->forward(…);
```

**Edit:**

Yep, that isn't very clear from the docs that there is a shared Events Manager, all examples I saw show only the usage of a freshly created instance. Looking at [the code of the Di/FactoryDefault](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/bf9da26e6e20ea05dd69881b9cd0c2536ec53bcb/ext/di/factorydefault.c#L289-L296) it seems there is a service for that with the same name. You can get it using the same syntax as above.

```
DI::getDefault()->get('eventsManager')->attach('dispatch', …);
```

The whole thing should look like this and must be setup somewhere after you configure your DI.

```
$di->get('eventsManager')->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
    switch ($exception->getCode()) {
        case Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
        case Phalcon\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
            $dispatcher->forward(array(
                'controller' => 'errors',
                'action' => 'show404'
            ));
            return false;
    }
});

$di->get('dispatcher')->setEventsManager($di->get('eventsManager'));
```

Comment: Shoot... sorry, I'm still new to Phalcon.  I think what I meant was if there's a way to get a hold of Phalcon's eventsmanager.  Rather - if I were to create a new instance of an eventsmanager, what do I then do with it?

Comment: That helps.  Thank you.  Any idea how to reattach it to the dispatcher?  I tried just adding it back into the DI via the set() method..

Comment: Yes, you've almost got it right. The updated code should work (if `$dispatcher` argument is the actual dispatcher, it should be).